# Highchart is only showing properly at localhost

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error when i try to upload it to webhost while it showing properly without any error when im using localhost. the php version that i use is the same with the webhost too.

this is what i found at console error
[image]

here's highchart code

```
   $(function(){
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'graph',
          scrollablePlotArea: {minWidth: 700},
      },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [<?php echo join($arrayTanggal, ',') ?>],
      tickWidth: 0,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: -40,
        y: -3
      }
    },
    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
    title: {
      text: null
    },  
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 3,
      y: 16,
      format: '{value:.,0f}'
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
  }, { // right y axis
    linkedTo: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    opposite: true,
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3,
      y: 16,
      format: '{value:.,0f}'
    },
    showFirstLabel: false
  }],
    legend: {
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      crosshairs: true
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Overall',
      color: '#dc3545',
      data: [<?php echo join($arrayAverage, ',') ?>],
      lineWidth: 3,
      marker: {
        radius: 8
      }
    },]
  });
});
```

appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: You error is saying that you need to swap your parameters of the `join()` function. So try to use the following: `join(',', $arrayTanggal)` and `join(',', $arrayAverage)`. See [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) (join is just an alias for implode)

Comment: Well you need so show some code of what you tried with my suggestions, so i can see what is going on. (try to update your question with this information so others can help too and we don't litter the comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, `join` is an alias for `implode`. So right syntax is `implode ( string $glue , array $pieces ) : string`.

And an answer is:

```php
<?php echo implode(',', $arrayTanggal) ?>
```

Comment: Read more in docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Your webhost has enabled "display errors" option in php.ini. So your JS code goes with PHP error message inside (`categories: [ PHP error message ]` and `data: [ PHP error message ]`)